# Lorentz transformations in matrix form (Matrix Multiplication problem)

Tags: matrices, transformation, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have recently been introduced to Lorentz transformations in the form of 4-Vectors, I have been told the following:
$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=\eta,$$
Where $\eta$ is the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -1 & 0 &  0 \\
    0       & 0 & -1 &  0 \\
   0       & 0 & 0 &  -1 
\end{bmatrix}
The relation supposedly holds for any transformation, $\Lambda$, but I am attempting to show that it works for:
$$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma      & -\beta \gamma & 0 & 0 \\
    -\beta \gamma       & \gamma & 0 &  0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1 &  0 \\
   0       & 0 & 0 &  1 
\end{bmatrix},$$
Which is just the Lorentz boost in x.

**My Problem is when it comes to the matrix multiplication**
I see that because $\Lambda$ is symmetric:
$$\Lambda^T=\Lambda,$$
by multiplication:
$$\Lambda^T\eta=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -\gamma & 0 &  0 \\
    0       & 0 & -1 &  0 \\
   0       & 0 & 0 &  -1 
\end{bmatrix},$$
Multiplying The above with $\Lambda$ gives:
$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma^2       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -\gamma^2 & 0 &  0 \\
    0       & 0 & -1 &  0 \\
   0       & 0 & 0 &  -1 
\end{bmatrix},$$
This is clearly not correct, as $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda$ should be:
$$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -1 & 0 &  0 \\
    0       & 0 & -1 &  0 \\
   0       & 0 & 0 &  -1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I have repeated the question many times and can not get to the correct answer. I initially thought it was something to do with the ordering of my multiplication, but even when I retry the calculation and taking the product of $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda^T$ first, I still get the incorrect answer.

If anyone can let me know where I am going wrong, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: What happened to the $\beta$?

Comment: Your $\Lambda^{T}\eta$ is incorrect. The $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ positions are nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have:
\begin{align*}\Lambda^T \eta&=\left[\begin{matrix}\gamma &\beta\gamma &0 &0\\-\beta\gamma &-\gamma &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &-1 &0\\ 0 &0 &0 &-1\end{matrix}\right]\\
\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda&=\left[\begin{matrix}\gamma^2-\beta^2\gamma^2 &0 &0 &0\\ 0 &-\gamma^2+\beta^2\gamma^2 &0 &0\\0 &0 &-1 &0\\ 0 &0 &0 &-1\end{matrix}\right].\end{align*}
If you simplify $\gamma^2-\beta^2\gamma^2$, you'll find that the LHS does indeed equal the RHS.